# how do i add a javascript library to a grails gsp file?

Tags: javascript, grails-2.0

how do I add a JavaScript library to a grails gsp file?
I am trying to add my custom JavaScript library to a web page using grails. This what I have so far:

```
<script src="mylibary.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your library to web-app/js directory and

add the following line to your gsp file

```
<g:javascript src="mylibrary.js"/>
```